# Print Template in Bartender Cloud API

Tags: bartender

I have an existing Bartender template file uploaded to the Cloud API. I can right-click and print the template, or go to the designer and view or make changes. My user has full access to our account.

Using Postman, this request:

```
https://am1.bartendercloud.com/api/actions?Wait=30s
{
    "PrintBTWAction": {
        "Document": "librarian://Main/Templates/TestAccessoryTemplate.btw",
        "Printer": "PDF",
        "Name": "Test Sample Print",
        "Description": "zzz",
        "SaveAfterPrint": false,
        "QueueAndContinue": false,
        "VerifyPrintJobIsComplete": true,
        "ReturnPrintSummary": true
    }
}
```

Gives me HTTP Status Code 200 and response:

```
{
    "Id": "4261c758-31a0-438f-a7e8-9c5810757a1d",
    "Status": "Faulted",
    "StatusUrl": "https://am1.bartendercloud.com:443/api/actions/4261c758-31a0-438f-a7e8-9c5810757a1d"
}
```

I'm (at the moment anyway) only using Cloud API. I am not running any cloud server, desktop agents or anything else. If possible, I'd prefer to not install anything else. The document attribute appears to take a local file reference, which I'd assume means have the server find the file on its machine, rather than my own. I have tried:

- Using query string file=librarian://Main/Templates/TestAccessoryTemplate.btw, and it says it cannot find that file. However, again that's the path shown on the Manage Files" section.
- I have tried giving it a file I know does not exist in the POST body,and I get the same error.
- I read that by default all Cloud API users get Librarian spaces Main and Temp. I assumed Main is the root directory of the "Manage Console" view.
- I tried putting the file in the root of the "Mange Console" view trying to see if it was a hierarchy, but it didn't help.
- I tried uploading a file to the "Main" space and even listing files in the Librarian space, but I got an RBAC error, despite using a fully privileged user.

All I want is to print a label programmatically. I can get it to work via the web console, but Seagull wants to fight me over the API. If I have to use this Librarian, I want to know how to get into it (preferrably without installing anything), or be able to just upload a .btw file with every print request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the printer wants to be either "PDF" or "printer:/".

Please be warned that the name returned by the Windows driver may have spaces in it, but is invalid when printing to Bartender using these services. Make sure the printer name is the one returned by the GetAllPrinters API call, and use the PrinterId and not the printer name.